# Base class / Action / Base / Generics type issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a base class:

```
public class LazyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>,
                                           IEnumerable,
                                           ICollection
```

It currently has a constructor that looks like:

```
public LazyObservableCollection(Action<LazyObservableCollection<T>> itemsFactory)
```

The idea is to have a lazy loadable ObservableCollection and be able to provide a factory so the user might do something like:

```
new LazyObservableCollection<string>(x =>
{
   x.Add("Item1");
   x.Add("Item2");
});
```

Obviously that is a trivial example and its more for the cases where determining the items is expensive and you don't want to load everything at once.

I then implemented a custom control that utilizes this class. I derived a class like so:

```
public class xxxItemCollection : LazyObservableCollection<xxxItem>
```

which has a constructor like this:

```
public xxxItemCollection(Action<LazyObservableCollection<xxxItem>> itemsFactory)
    : base(itemsFactory)
```

This is all working, but here's my question... to me, I don't like that `xxxItemCollection` takes an `Action<LazyObservableCollection<xxxItem>>` for the `itemsFactory`. I believe it should be `Action<xxxItemCollection>`, but then I can't pass `xxxItemCollection` to the base class. The error message is actually about converting it to a `IEnumerable<xxxItem>`.

Is there a way in the derived class to pass the derived type to the base class? Or should I be structuring the base class in a different way?

Comment: Why not use a [Lazy<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx)... e.g. `Lazy<ObservableCollection<T>>`?  Also when asking, try to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the full error that you get. That makes it easier for others to help.

Comment: @DennisKuypers I can't use Lazy as WPF will bind to the Lazy object rather then the ObservableCollection object, so it won't see any of the ObservableCollection notifications or interfaces. My solution is a live ObservableCollection that lazy loads its items through the factory.

Comment: If you have a way to safely convert from LazyObservableCollection<xxxItem> to xxxItemCollection, you could do 
public xxxItemCollection(Action<xxxItemCollection> itemsFactory)
    : base(new Action<LazyObservableCollection<xxxItem>>(a => itemsFactory(Convert(a, typeof(xxxItemCollection)))))

Comment: @DennisKuypers error is Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Action<xxxItemCollection>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<xxxItem>'

Comment: @MBakardzhiev I took your idea and did base(x => itemsFactory((xxxItemCollection)x)) and that did the trick. No point in doing the convert since its guaranteed to be xxxItemCollection which is derived from the proper type. Thanks!

Comment: You should be careful when doing such cast because it will compile but might cause trouble at runtime. You need something safer.